# How do I write less RewriteRules?

Tags: .htaccess

Years ago I installed link building scrips in multiple sub directories on my site. Spiders picked picked up the addresses and to this day they show up.

I can redirect them all with 13 different RewriteRules but I need do do this for 13 subdirectories. Is there a way to accomplish this without 169 lines of code?

```
RewriteRule ^adult/join/ http://www.domain/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/stats/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/details/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/overall-stats/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/lost_pw/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/review/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/reviews/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/rank/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/search/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/category/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/user_cpl/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/page/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adult/app/ http://www.domain.com/adult/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^teen/join/ http://www.domain/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/stats/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/details/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/overall-stats/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/lost_pw/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/review/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/reviews/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/rank/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/search/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/category/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/user_cpl/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/page/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teen/app/ http://www.domain.com/teen/ [R=301,L]
```

And then for ^gay ^gayteen ^senior ect.

Comment: You need to design a [rewrite rule](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/), or alternatively handle these type of responses in your application where ever you handle your routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(adult|teen|gay|gayteen|senior)/(?:join|stats|details|overall-stats|lost_pw|reviews?|rank|search|category|user_cpl|page|app)/? http://www.domain.com/$1/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Only one line ;-)

EDIT: with domain option:

```
RewriteRule ^((?:adult|teen|gay|gayteen|senior)/)?(?:join|stats|details|overall-stats|lost_pw|reviews?|rank|search|category|user_cpl|page|app)/? http://www.domain.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Perfect! can I include the main domain.com as well?

Comment: I do not understand. He is there ! If the domain is the same you can even delete `http://www.domain.com/`

Comment: I meant so it worked for domain.com/join/ and domain.com/stats/ ect. But I can do it on another line, not a big deal.

Comment: Yes, you can change the code, I add this in my answer.

Comment: As this answer solved your problem, [you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking on **tick mark** on top-left of this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242) Thank you !